# Using drupal_http_post() to submit to external site: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: webforms

I intended to make a module that utilized `drupal_http_request` with a webform so that the form gets validated before it gets sent to an external url.

I actually was recommended this method over `$form['#action']` from a [previous inquiry](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74793/validating-a-webform-with-captcha-locally-before-submitting-to-an-external-url) earlier. I did as recommended, thought it worked, but found out that I was mistaken.

I did some troubleshooting and concluded my module is the culprit since:

1. The module utilizing `$form['#action']` had no problems posting to our external url/web app and another external site/service for testing HTTP POST submissions (http://requestb.in)
2. The module utilizing `drupal_http_post` could neither post to our external url/web app nor requestb.in

My setup uses the following:

- Drupal 6.x
- Webform 6.x-3.17

My custom module contains the following code.

```
function webform_to_data_repo_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_765') {
        $url = 'external.url.goes.here';
    $headers = array(
                 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               );

$response = drupal_http_request($url, $headers, 'POST', http_build_query($form_state['values'], '', '&'));
   }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my module? Just wanted to make it post to some external URL.

Comment: I don't completely understand how your result differs from your expectation. Is $response not an object as described in the [API docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/6)?

Comment: Check the out of $response at the end & see what it gives you..

Comment: My apologies for not being completely clear.

What I intended to do really was to make webform 765 to validate locally and post externally.

As for the $response, it doesn't give me any for some reason. When I submit through the form, all I get really is a "Thank you, your submission has been received", but this is what one would get when you submit through a webform, right?

Comment: Interestingly, my other module that uses $form['#action'] to submit externally instead of drupal_http_request returns an "ok" message.

I would use $form['#action']. Problem is, I want the form to be validated before it submits externally, which is why I'm forced to use drupal_http_request.

Comment: Install and enable the Devel module and then add a line at the end that says `dpm($response);` and tell us what shows up in the yellow box.

Comment: And by "at the end" I mean at the end of the code you pasted in, not the end of the Devel module.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for the pointers.

I realized that my custom module that uses the webform module to submit to an external url (via drupal_http_request) had to be written as two separate functions: one using hook_form_alter and one using a custom submit handler. The code is as follows.

```
<?php

function webform_to_data_repo_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

//I only want form 765 to submit externally //
if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_765') {
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_additional_submit_handler';
 }
}

function my_additional_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {

$url = 'your.external.url.here'
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',);
$response = drupal_http_request($url, $headers, 'POST', http_build_query($form_state['values'], '', '&'));

}




?>
```

As a side note, I never got to test the result of using `dpm($response)` using the Devel module as beth suggested.

I'm using a webform (via the webform module) to test. What I wanted to happen are two things.

1. The webform validates the submission which in turn would keep a log of the submission through Drupal (webform module by default and by design).
2. Simultaneously submit inputs from #1 to external url.

For the longest time, only #1 is happening and I can't seem to make Devel look into `$response` because that variable only exists when there's an attempt on submission. How does one make Devel module load when a successful submission has been made through a Webform? I guess this is another question for another time.

Comment: Do you think this might work on D7 ?