# Webforms, Remote Post, and Redirecting

Tags: webforms

I'm a new Drupal dev trying to get a form to work the way the client's current form works. As it is now, the client has a form on their site that submits to a different site that processes the form data. For clarity, the action attribute on the form tag is set to a specific URL where the form data is processed.

We're rebuilding the client's site in Drupal and I've got the form built on their site using the Webform module. I tried simply setting the redirection location to the other site. As you would expect, the form submits, then redirects to the other page, but none of the data goes to the other site.

After reading suggestions, I installed and enabled the Remote Post module. On the form, I added the processing URL as the Target URL and left the Redirection Location alone (so its still the processing URL). When I submit the form, it redirects to the processing URL, but again none of the data is there.

I've tried removing the Redirection Location URL, but then the form simply submits and takes me to a  "Thank You" page.

I've tried snippets of supposedly working code to no avail. This one would be fine for our purposes since Drupal doesn't need to record or process any of the form data, just send it over to the other site. When I put these code snippets into my template.php (and customize them for our usage), nothing with the form or submission behavior changes, but I may have just typed something in incorrectly.

[Webform - Submit values from Drupal 7 from to external url](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94884/webform-submit-values-from-drupal-7-from-to-external-url/96575#96575)

This is literally the last thing I have to work on for this site and any help I can get would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the existing site submit a GET or POST request?  Are you verifying that there isn't any POST data being sent in your request using firebug/chromes net tab?

Comment: The current site submits a POST request. 

I can see (using Chrome's DevTools) that a POST request is being sent. Part of the problem may have been that the hidden fields were set up with Tokens, not just plain hidden fields. I've changed that for a few of the fields and can now see their values in the payload. The remote site is still not showing the data though. I'll keep poking around with the hidden fields, thanks for the tip!