# Webform: POST data and send user to external URL

Tags: 7, webforms

I was reading this interesting post: [Webform - Submit values from Drupal 7 from to external url](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94884/webform-submit-values-from-drupal-7-from-to-external-url)

I'd like to know: instead of just sending the data via POST and keeping the user on the Drupal site, how would you send the user to the URL the form values are posted to, so that they would arrive at the new URL and see a new form with the values they submitted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That post is accurate. You just need to set the `#action` of the form to be the URL you want to be POSTed to:

```
$form['#action'] = 'https://some.other.site.com/destination';
```