# Creating a workflow

Tags: webforms, workflows

I'm learning drupal, I create a web form for duty travel that the user submitted. Now I want to create a workflow so after submitted the webform should be sent to manager for validation or cancelling after that he add some comments and files and resend it to the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup complete workflow using these modules with webform:

[Webform Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_workflow)

> This is a Drupal 7 module which allows assigning workflow 'states' to
>   webform submissions. Users can be notified when submissions change
>   state. Permissions can be set to control access to submissions based
>   on their state. The states themselves are fieldable Drupal entities.

[Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow)

> workflows are made up of workflow states. Transitions between states
>   can be allowed per role. For example, a workflow with the states
>   Draft, Review, and Published could be assigned to the Story node type.
>   Only users with role 'chief editor' can set Stories to the published
>   state. You can set up the Workflow to alter states from form, page,
>   comment, a special block, and a special workflow tab. Additionally,
>   the submodule Workflow Access allows you to manage view/edit/delete
>   permissions for content types per User role and Workflow state.
>
> Transitions between workflow states can have actions assigned to them.
>   In our example, we could assign an action so that when the story moves
>   from the Draft state to the Review state an email is sent out. Another
>   action could be assigned to the transition from Review to Published so
>   that the node's status is set to Published

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/bwypzg) thank you i try the module but i want to know is it possible to add fields in the webform for example the user sent the webform to the manager, and when the manager receive it , he download pictures and at the same time upload others pictures then he  validate the webform

Answer (score 2):

You can use hooks to change almost anything in the webform like additional submit handlers can be handled, validation can be done, elements can be added, etc.

Refer the already existing answers, it will be helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174165/drupal-7-webform-submit-hook

[Webform - Submit values from Drupal 7 from to external url](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94884/webform-submit-values-from-drupal-7-from-to-external-url)